# Notify_url PAYPAL not work for a few days!Why?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a problem with receiving notifications for receiving payment via PAYPAL .
My form is:

```
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='link for notify variable paypal'>
```

My problem is that yesterday and today `notify_url` has not received variable of payment.

Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: Have you checked your IPN History in PayPal to see if it shows anything getting sent?

Comment: I would also set your IPN address within your account if you can. I've found that to be more reliable.